# python -- import module in same directory

Tags: python, module, package, importerror, python-import

I have a project setup like this (tell me if it's wrong):

```
 project/
     module_1/
         __init__.py
         foo.py
     module_2/
         __init__.py
         bar.py
```

In foo.py:

```
from module_2 import bar
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named module_2
```

However, if I change my project setup to this:

```
 project/
     module_1/
         __init__.py
         foo.py
         module_2/
             __init__.py
             bar.py
```

it works.  How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you importing while in foo.py ?

Comment: Yeah -- it happens whether the import statement is in module_one/foo.py or module_one/__init__.py

Comment: Because module2 is one step up while you are in foo.
You are supposed to write ../module2 import bar.
Note the ../

Comment: there's no __init__.py in my top directory.  should there be?

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative import:

```
from ..module_2 import bar
```

Then you refer to it as just bar: bar.method().

EDIT:
add a `__main__.py` to `project` and run it from one level up, with

```
python -m project
```

Comment: it gives the "attempted relative import from another package" error